# Function Argument shows expected "," separator error in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am following the Stanford CS193P course and trying to understand UIGestureRecognizer. I have used the same methods as the instructor but the code shows 1 error in the IBOutlet section. We I try to call the change scale function from the FaceView, with (_:) in the argument , it shows an error expected "," error at that point. Kindly help.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var expression = FacialExpression(eyes: .Closed, eyeBrows: .Normal, mouth: .Smile) {
        didSet {
            updateUI()
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var faceView: FaceView!{
        didSet{

            faceView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPinchGestureRecognizer(
                target: faceView,  action: Selector(FaceView.changeScale(_:))
                ))
            updateUI()
        }

    }

    private var mouthCurvatures = [FacialExpression.Mouth.Frown:-1.0,.Grin: 0.5,.Smile:1.0,.Smirk: -0.5,.Neutral: 0.0 ]

    private var eyeBrowTilts = [FacialExpression.EyeBrows.Relaxed:0.5,.Furrowed:-0.5,.Normal:0.0]


    private func updateUI(){


        switch expression.eyes {
        case .Open: faceView.eyesOpen = true
        case .Closed: faceView.eyesOpen = false
        case .Squinting: faceView.eyesOpen = false

         }

        faceView.mouthCurvature = mouthCurvatures[expression.mouth] ?? 0.0
        faceView.eyeBrowTilt = eyeBrowTilts[expression.eyeBrows] ?? 0.0

    }

}
```

Comment: What does the actual `changeScale` function look like?

Comment: `func changeScale(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {}`. You can find all the code on Stanford's website http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/node/427

Comment: In Swift ≥ 2.2 you might use the `#selector(FaceView.changeScale(_:)` syntax.

Comment: func changeScale(recogniser : UIPinchGestureRecognizer){
    
        switch recogniser.state {
        case .Changed, .Ended:
            scale *= recogniser.scale
            recogniser.scale = 1.0
            
        default :
            break 
        }
    
    }

Comment: @vadian i understand but am using the old version right now, hence i used "Selector"

Comment: Actually the **old** syntax is simply `... action: "changeScale:" ...`

Comment: @vadian do you mean there has to be no selector?

Comment: The old literal syntax infers the type `Selector` that means the compiler uses implicitly the initializer `Selector(string : String)`.